# how to use scrollIt.js in different pages with different topOffset?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a nice jQuery plugin that i use for my site.

[scrollIt.js](http://www.bytemuse.com/scrollIt.js)

In the option section:

```
$.scrollIt({
  upKey: 38,             // key code to navigate to the next section
  downKey: 40,           // key code to navigate to the previous section
  easing: 'linear',      // the easing function for animation
  scrollTime: 600,       // how long (in ms) the animation takes
  activeClass: 'active', // class given to the active nav element
  onPageChange: null,    // function(pageIndex) that is called when page is changed
  topOffset: 0           // offste (in px) for fixed top navigation
});
```

I set the "topOffset" to "-160", and it works fine. Now on the other page i'm calling the same function but now I want the "topOffset" to be "0". How would i achieve that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the problem myself by doing this:

```
if( $(".main-body").hasClass("home-vertical-scroll") ){
    var scrollItTopOffset = 0;
}

else{
    var scrollItTopOffset = -160;
};

   $(function(){
        $.scrollIt({
            upKey: 38,           
            downKey: 40,         
            easing: 'linear',      
            scrollTime: 600,      
            onPageChange: null,   
            topOffset: scrollItTopOffset        
        });
    });
```

In case someone want the answer.